# Mimicing externals property without comitting to the top level repository

Tags: svn

I have an "engine" repository laid out like

```
/Engine
  /Modules
```

And a "game" repository that wants to interlace with the Engine layout like:

```
/Engine
  /Modules
    /Game
```

I'm trying to figure out how to arrange things so that

1. The folder structure explained above is set up correctly as the superset of the two repositories.
2. The engine repository doesn't have any references to the game repository.
3. The game repository has all the meta information about eg: externals.

SVN externals really don't want to do what I'm trying to do.  The obvious fix of having an external on the engine repository pointing to the `Game` folder in the game repository requires that I commit the external pattern to the engine repository, which I don't want to do.

I can create a few dozen separate externals in the game repository to subfolders of /Engine and /Modules in the engine repository, manually recreating the top level structure of the engine repository.  This works but it's really messy and won't automatically pick up any new folders added to the engine repository (I don't expect there to be many, but still).

Are there any other options I could consider?  I don't expect there to be any well supported options but I'm willing to be a bit hacky.

Answer (score 2):

You really have to select one of 2 possible solutions:

- Jump into real pure Configuration Management world with its tools, methodology, etc (svn:externals just *mimics* somehow CM)
- Still use SVN externals, but not in "the obvious fix" style and go a little more bizarre instead

I can't recommend **The Definitive Tool (tm)** for CM (and it will be offtopic here anyway), but SVN-style *with externals*, which can be usable for you, will include (TBT!, I have not SVN and not use it now)

1. Empty (without own content) "wrapper" repository
2. Externals in the root of wrapper-repository, which hold all references to used Engine and Game repos (game, nested into engine tree, is main unclean for me question and possible problem, additional research needed, while, according to even slightly outdated [SVN Book](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html), it can be done)

If use book's samples of definitions

```
$ svn propget svn:externals calc
third-party/sounds             http://svn.example.com/repos/sounds
third-party/skins -r148        http://svn.example.com/skinproj
third-party/skins/toolkit -r21 http://svn.example.com/skin-maker
```

as base (note definition for `third-party/skins/toolkit` after previous `third-party/skins`: your case of nested externals) and given your repositories structure, I'll suggest definitions like

```
. /URL-OF-ENGINE-REPO
/engine/modules/game /URL-OF-GAME-REPO
```

In this situation *independent Game repo* doesn't have|store any information about relations with Engine repo *automagically* and req.3 seems failed, but:

- you can always get this data with `svn propget svn:externals` in the root of wrapper-repo by hand
  or
- get updates of this data with post-commit (?) hook of wrapper-repo, store it in ignored file in WC of Game repo or maybe even as custom svn-property (stored in repo, not only in WC, versioned, but will require additional "technical" commit in game repo, when change of wrapper-externals arrive to game repo)